# Parsing US dateformat as Canadian dateformat throws "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#

I've inherited  a custom DLL code to use with SSIS but I'm not a C# savvy. the code used to work on Win 2003 machine but not anymore on 2012 one even if datetime settings are the same

Here's a pretty simple example

```
DateTime aa;

 try
 {
System.IFormatProvider format = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
aa = System.DateTime.ParseExact("02/09/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy",format,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
 }
```

> $exception {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}  System.Exception {System.FormatException}

If I change the format to something like "en-GB" or "it-IT"  , it would work but I need to parse the US date format as Canadian.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please, format your code before posting!

Comment: A Canadian says "Eh?" at that string.  You probably ought to consider CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: To parse a us date, the most convinient way imo is `DateTime.Parse("09/01/2014", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
System.IFormatProvider format = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
var aa = System.DateTime.ParseExact("2014/02/09", "yyyy/MM/dd", format);
```

Is because the date separator character in Canada is `'-'`, but the date separator in your date string is `'/'`. Hence, it fails.

You can fix this by changing your date format specifier to use explicit separators by escaping the slashes, like so:

```
var aa = System.DateTime.ParseExact("2014/02/09", "yyyy\\/MM\\/dd", format);
```

Alternatively:

```
var aa = System.DateTime.ParseExact("2014/02/09", @"yyyy\/MM\/dd", format);
```

Note that just putting the `'/'` character into a date format specification does NOT mean "there should be a `'/'` character here". It means "there should be a date separator character here", and which character that date separator is depends on the locale.

Because you specified Canadian, the the `'\'` specifier was actually interpreted as meaning there should be a `'-'` character there.

To override this behaviour, you can specify `\\/` instead, as per my example above, and this tells the parser to treat the `/` verbatim instead of treating it as the date separator for the specified locale.

I should also mention that you can also just use the "InvariantCulture", which will also work because the date separator in the InvariantCulture is always `'/'`.

Comment: Perfect , I also figured it out after removing the slahes in both format and value but didn't know how to escape it. Thanks a lot